# LBP Local Binary Pattern for mouth detection in front face

Tags: opencv, cascade-classifier

There is someone who can direct me to find a lbp cascade classifier for mouth detection?
I looked for but i didn't found anything. I found only haar files, i want to know if someone have a lbp classifier. Haar classifiers are so slow, decrease of 10 fps in my app using haar. Thank you guys.

Comment: find out who trained the haar classifier and what kind of dataset he used and train the lbp yourself.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I'm interested in understanding how to train the classifiers but honestly I do not know where to start. Do you have any interesting links to suggest?

Comment: there are some official and inofficial tutorials. But you'll need a lot of training data.

Comment: Ok, Thank you again :)

Comment: @RobertoManfreda did you manage to find the code for a lbp classifier ? really interested in this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Sandeep sorry i changed my S.O. profile so i haven't seen your question. Anyway yes! I managed with classifiers in last times. I can give you a good address.
I worked with haar cascade-classifiers the process is very simple but you need a lot of training data!
Basically you'll need a set of positive samples(that includes the Object that you want to scan) and a set negative samples(that NOT contains the object that you want to scan).

**EXAMPLE:**
Supposing you want to scan potholes using opencv and an haar cascade-classifier:
you'll need a set of images of streets that contains potholes(positive samples) and a set of image of streets that NOT contains potholes(negative samples).

I leave you a link that helped me so much: http://www.academia.edu/9149928/A_complete_guide_to_train_a_cascade_classifier_filter

This example uses a GitHub project i here's the link: https://github.com/sauhaardac/Haar-Training

Hope to be helpful, bye :D